# tfs build schedule

Tags: build, tfs

Before each build I do "get specific version" and get the code for all valid changesets. Now if I schedule a nightly build, how can I do a "get specific version" to get the correct code before the build?

Comment: Is there any pattern to what specific version you get? Aren't you always getting latest version?

Comment: Are you building on your local machine or are you using team build?

Comment: I am using team build and doing a get specific version based on changesets.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I assume you've configured/edited your build definition: `Trigger->Schedule` then in `Process->Advanced->Get Version`just put the changeset you want with the format:

- **C**[your_changeset_number] Example: C123

You could even use a label there with: **L**[label_name] Example: LMYLABEL20140213

[image]